# Google Maps only displays when I hit cmd+shift+R

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a weird error happening with my google maps code.

On local it works perfect.

On the live staging server however, when first viewing the page I get the initMap is not a function error.

The tricky part is, if I do a hard refresh (cmd+shift+r) the map works fine and no errors.

But if I try to visit the page again(either going to the URL directly or clicking a link to the page) I get an error.

It only displays the map properly when using cmd+shift+r to refresh the page.

Does anyone have ideas as to what could cause this? My code is below. Thank you very much.

Here's the error:

```
Uncaught Ib {message: "initMap is not a function", name: 
"InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Ib 
(https://maps.googleapis.com/m…MY_KEY_j163:51"}
```

Here's my script tags in the order I'm loading them:

**_foot.php:**

```
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Fancybox jQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
  <!-- main js -->
  <script defer type='text/javascript' src='<?=  $config->urls->templates 
  . 'lib/main.js' ; ?>'></script>
  <!-- Google Maps -->
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
  key=MY_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
// Initialize markers
let markers = [];
// Initialized map
let map;
// Initialize the infoWindow
let infoWindow;
// Initialize Soho
let soho;
// Initialize marker
let marker;

/**
 * Lifestyle Google Map
 *
 */
function initMap() {

  /* The Sol Hollywood Location */
  soho = {coords: { lat: 34.092786, lng: -118.31358620000003}, icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/homegardenbusiness.png', title: 'Sol Hollywood'};

  /* Create The Map */
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(soho.coords.lat, soho.coords.lng),
    zoom: 12
  });

  /**
   * Add New markers
   * options object
   */
  function addMarker(options) {
    // Create the marker
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: options.coords,
      map: map,
    });

    // Check if an icon has been passed into options, if so set it.
    if (options.icon) {
      marker.setIcon(options.icon);
    }

    // Create the info window
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: options.title
    });

    // When marker is clicked, set and show info window
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infoWindow.setContent(options.title);
      infoWindow.open(map, this);
    });

    // Collect the markers
    markers.push(marker);
  }

  // Add The Sol Hollywood Marker
  addMarker(soho);

  // Ajax get request to grab local spot coords for map.
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'json',
    url: "/local-spot-get-coords",
    success: function(data) {
      // loop over the json coords from the PHP page and add a marker for each
      for (let key in data) {
          addMarker(data[key]);
      }
    }
  });
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by calling the initMap myself and removing the callback from the map script.

So at the end of my main.js I just called initMap:

**main.js**

```
initMap();
```

And in the footer where I load the maps script, I remove the callback:

**_foot.php**

```
<!-- Google Maps -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_HERE"></script>
```